# json schmea - how to validate a specific value in an array of strings when other values may be present

Tags: jsonschema

the response below comes back with 3 separate string types in an array.

```
{
Messages: [2]
0: "message 1"
1: "message 2"
}
{
Messages: [3]
0: "message 1"
1: "message 2"
2: "message 3"
}
{
Messages: [1]
0: "message 2"
}
```

i want to test that if "message 1" is present in the output, validation passes. the other messages can be present but i don't care. i just want to test that "message 1" is present. the problem i have now is that when other objects don't have "message 1" then my validation fails. like the third object of the example above.

i've tried the constant, anyOf, allOf, oneOf, enum keywords but i can't seem to get it right.

here's just a snippet of my json schema that pertains to the array above. this is a very complex schema so i'm just sharing my problem area.

below fails because the 3rd object does not contain "message 1". same result if i use constant, anyOf, allOf, etc. keywords

```
"messages": {
   "type": "array",
   "items": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": ["message 1"]
      }    
}
```

does anybody know how i can get around this?

Answer (score 0):

do you care about position? that is, will "message 1" always be the first item in the array?

if it can be in any position, and you are using draft6 or later, `contains` will match any position: `"contains": {"const": "message 1"}`

if it is always the first position, the array form of `items` (or `prefixItems` in the most current json schema spec) can be used, e.g. `"items": [{"const": "message 1"}], "minItems": 1`. in the array form, each array element of `items` applies only to the corresponding item in the instance array. the `minItems` keyword is necessary as an empty instance array would otherwise pass.

Comment: i do not care about position. as long as "message 1" is present in any one of the messages or objects. i tried using contains and i'm still getting errors in postman because the other objects don't contain "message 1".

`
"Messages": {
           "type": "array",
           "items": {
               "type": "string",
            },
            "contains": {
                "const": "message 1"
            }
`
`
data.Members[0].Coverages[0].BenefitCoverages[3].Messages[0] should be equal to constantdata.Members[0].Coverages[0].BenefitCoverages[3].Messages should contain a validitem

Comment: it seems to pass for me: https://jsonschema.dev/s/zyONT

Comment: I think you mean that the "message 1" can be present across any of multiple objects containing a "Messages" key, but you haven't shown that structure or a schema describing it. can you reproduce a failing instance on jsonschema.dev and share that?

Comment: add another object with only "message 2" in the response like below.
`
{
"message": ["message 1", "message 2] 
}
{
"message": "message 2" 
}
`

Comment: will do later today. need to step away for a bit. thanks so much for taking the time to help!

Comment: I think I understand a little better, but you need just one instance to describe. if those objects are in an array like `[{"Messages: [...]}, {"Messages": [...]}` that can be described, but I'm not sure if that is what you intend.

Comment: you are correct in your last assumption.

[{"Messages: [...]}, {"Messages": [...]}

as long as "message 1" is in the response just once in any of the objects returned validation is successful.

Comment: seems to pass https://jsonschema.dev/s/m2rmk. but i can't get it to pass in postman. weird.

Comment: but then again. this passes validation also. https://jsonschema.dev/s/Jq4mZ

Comment: putting the message below 'hello' changes the whole structure and needs another level of json schema. try this one on for size, it should allow anything with a 'message 1' below messages in the 'hello' array: https://jsonschema.dev/s/B1Auy

Comment: that's the one! i understand now that i needed to be up one level. thanks for your support!